# Doctrine2 DQL equivalent in query builder

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I prefer to enforce the use of the query builder in my project, I find the sql it produces is more predictable than writing straight DQL (It has done some very weird joins on me in the past). However, I've found that this DQL is the only way I can do this aggregation query.

```
    $q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(<<<DQL
      SELECT IDENTITY(p.business, 'id') as businessId, SUM(p.amount) as points
      FROM APIBundle\Entity\Point p
      WHERE IDENTITY(p.user, 'id') = :user
      GROUP BY p.business
DQL
  )
      ->setParameter('user', $user->getId())
    ;

    return $q;
```

Is this my only option or can the querybuilder be utilised for the same result?

I'm getting some understanding that the querybuilder is more of an orm tool with hydration etc and not as useful for more array based non hydrated query resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, aggregation is a tricky bit for any ORM. You can use [Low level API](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#low-level-api) to wrap DQL part into query builder, if you like:

```
$queryBuilder->add('select', 'SUM(p.amount) as points');
```